# Instant Run error in Android Studio 2.3

Tags: android, android-studio

My Android Studio is 2.3 Version.
When I Enable Instant Run (If I Disable Instant Run, there is no error) and Run app, I get error:

[image: Application Installation Failed]

I click "OK":

```
DELETE_FAILED_INTERNAL_ERROR
Error while Installing APKs
```

Do you have any idea with this error?

Comment: disable instant run and try re-install the app.

Comment: Same situation. Any solution to use Instant run?

Comment: Tick "Prefer INTERNAL STORAGE" on your phone

Comment: I am using Genymotion for simulators, can you tell me more details steps to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

It can't seem to uninstall the previous version of your app. Just go ahead and uninstall it manually this time. It should work afterwards.

Comment: I run app on my phone, and it don't have previous version of my app

Comment: No app with the same package name?

Comment: Try Build > Clean Project

Comment: Yes, I just try a package with a random name -> the same error
Clean Project ->  not working

Comment: Try to upgrade your version of gradle.
`classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'` in your project `build.gradle`

Comment: my classpath is classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

Comment: @BaoLocDinh How did you fixed it? Did you find any solution?

Comment: This error  because my phone refer install app on EXTERNAL storage. 
But my app does not have any permission to access it.
Tick "Prefer INTERNAL STORAGE"
Hope it helps for you

Answer (score -1):

If I am understanding correctly, you are attempting to emulate your app on one of the Studio's built in emulators. I believe the problem is your APK is either corrupted, a Gradle Build Error occurred, or the APK and the API of your emulator are two different versions.

I would suggest backing up your project, and then reinstall a newer version of the project.

Comment: I run app on my phone, not emulator

Comment: Ok, then I suggest that you power-cycle your phone, after uninstalling any previous versions, then try again.

Comment: How to fix? @BaoLocDinh

Comment: Tick "Prefer INTERNAL STORAGE" on your phone